# I need to show the panel on top of the drop down list.Panel is distorted because of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I had dynamically created the drop down list and placed in the tablecell and based on the button click i need to show the panel on top of the drop down list. But I’m facing the problem that whenever I’m placing the panel on the top of the drop down list, the drop list control is getting displayed on top of the panel. Any help is appreciated.

Note: I’m facing this problem only in IE6, remaining browsers is working fine (IE8, FF, and Chrome)

width: 506px; height: 236px;">

OnClick="OkClicked" />

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with style='z-index: 1000' attribute

Comment: Thanks for fast response but giving 1000 to z-index is not working